# Prevent SailJS waterline to create columns which are used for association

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am new to NodeJs/sailsJS.

I have following models:

**Person**

```
module.exports = {
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,
  attributes: {
      person_id: {
           type: 'integer',
           primaryKey: true,
           autoIncrement: true
      },
      user: {
           model: 'user'
      },
      person_name: {
          type: 'string',
          required: true,
          size: 128
      },
      person_birthdate: {
          type: 'date'
      },
      person_gender: {
          type: 'string',
          size: 1
      }
  }
};
```

**User**

```
module.exports = {
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,
  attributes: {
      user_id: {
          type: 'integer',
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: false
      },
      person: {
          model: 'person'
      }
  }
};
```

It creates column `person` in `user` table and column `user` in `person` table. How do I stop these columns to pop up and still be able to use waterline. Entity Framework in C# MVC is able to provide that functionality, so I think there might be a way to do it in SailsJs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in file `config/models.js` this line: `migrate: 'safe'` to exported configuration.
About model settings you can read here: [sailsjs.org/documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings)